# Can I Delete an NPC?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I had asked Cass to wait outside the Van Graffs while I snuck in for 'Heartache By The Number' and when I exitted she wasn't there. Being immensely confused, she showed up on the map, but knowing no way around it, I used player.placeatme to bring her too me, I should have used movetome or whatever that command is, and she did in fact appear... then the one who I couldn't see before (she was somehow invisible) appeared and now I have two gun toting, firey redheaded companions. Is it possible to remove one of them so I no longer have a duo of Roses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the console and click on the extra Cass to select her. Then, type `disable` and poof, she'll be gone.